# Почему не получается загрузить фото во ВКонтакте?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, асинхронность

Есть такой код. Он работает, может асинхронно загружать картинки на сервер, но мне не хочется создавать лишних файлов, так что я использую BytesIO

```
import ...

image_url = '...'
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=TOKEN)
api = vk_session.get_api()

upload_url = api.photos.getMessagesUploadServer()['upload_url']

with open('/tmp/photo.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(httpx.get(image_url).content)
files = {'photo': open('/tmp/photo.jpg', 'rb')}

async def fetch(url, file):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        s = await client.post(url, files=file)
        return s.json()


async def main():
    responses = await asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(upload_url, files))
    print(responses)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Но c BytesIO код не работает, поле 'photo' пустое

```
import ...
image_url = '...'
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=TOKEN)
api = vk_session.get_api()

upload_url = api.photos.getMessagesUploadServer()['upload_url']

files = {'photo': BytesIO(httpx.get(image_url).content)}

async def fetch(url, file):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        s = await client.post(url, files=file)
        return s.json()


async def main():
    responses = await asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(upload_url, files))
    print(responses)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Ответ - не ошибка, но поле 'photo' - пустое. Почему так происходит? Как загружать фото на сервера ВКонтакте, не создавая временных файлов?

Comment: Обратите, пожалуйста, внимание на то, что для этого есть отдельные методы в классе [`vk_api.upload.VkUpload`](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upload.html).

Comment: Потому что ВК требует указать имя файла. При чтении существующего файла имя берётся из файла, а у BytesIO имени нет.

Comment: В документации aiohttp есть пример прописывания filename https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Comment: @andreymal спасибо. У меня получилось асинхронно загрузить фото